# Getting selected dropdown value for custom attribute in Magento automatically

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get a custom dropdown attribute's selected value using

```
echo $_product->getProductSize();
```

and

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('product_size');
```

Then, I clear my cache and reindex and reload my page. I tried selecting a value from the dropdown but either one returns anything. So basically, my question is, how can I retrieve the selected value from a custom dropdown attribute? I'm planning on using this to display different contents on my product page depending on the selected value. Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Addition: I'm trying to call it on the product page where the same dropdown is called.

After trying to play with the attribute a little bit through the admin panel, I noticed how the value I selected echoed on the page. However, I was hoping of being able to retrieve it dynamically on the frontend. Is this possible? For example, in the frontend, the customer selects option B, then I would display information related to option B. Then if he changed to option D then the information would change to option D's information.

Comment: Where are you trying to get this value? On which page?

Comment: I'm trying to get it on the product page where the same dropdown is.

Answer (score 17):

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('product_size');
```

It should work unless your theme is dependent on this setting 'Used in Product Listing' and 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end' for your attribute from backend in Manage Attribute.
Additionally check if your attribute code does not contain any spaces. Although magento do not let you use spaces in attribute code through form submission but if attribute is created programmatically or from sql query then it is possible. Other wise it is something else not your code or attribute causing problem.

Comment: How to escape html to these values?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/569/how-to-escape-output-data#answer-571

Comment: and how to obtain the value for a CUSTOM OPTION dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this code, it might be useful.
The code fetches all custom options with their values

```
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $value)
{
    echo "<br/><strong>".$value->getTitle()."</strong><br/>";
    $values = $value->getValues();// Getting Values if it has option values, case of select,dropdown,radio,multiselect
    ?>
    <select id = "<?php echo 'select_'.$value->getId() ?>" name = "<?php echo 'options['.$value->getId() .']'?>">
    <?php
    foreach ($values as $val)
        {
            echo "<option price = " . $val->getPrice(). " value = ".$val->getOptionTypeId() . ">" .$val->getTitle()."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    $i++; 
}
```

Note : The code outputs the **custom options** & their **values** just as they would be required if they were to be used for adding the product to the cart.
You can remove the select if you just want to get the option values(to reduce the complexity of the code).

Comment: This does work to display them, but it doesn't use the option's price when adding it to the cart.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code

```
<?php if ($_product->getData('attribute_name')): ?>
<p><?php echo nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')
->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work at all. I changed the dropdown value and it didn't display the selected value.

Comment: http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-attributes-value/ Just refer this link.may this link will guide you at right direction

Comment: thanks. I've tried this as well but all it returned was No when I tried to echo the value.

Comment: This also worked when I tried to get an attribute from a customer. I replaced `$_product` with a customer object.